# why there are so many CLOSE_WAIT stage when i set worker_processes=8 in nginx?

Tags: post, nginx, redis

deal all~ i have a problem with nginx: there are too many **timeout** with my service. ye, as guessed, there are two many **CLOSE_WAIT** stage, when i run command “netstat -tc | grep CLOSE“。

**Background**:

recently, i do some anti-spam work, and provide a server interface using nginx(http **post** method). i also use redis to store some statistic data, shared by 
eight nginx worker process.

**Problem**:

when i set worker_processes=1 in nginx.conf, there exist little CLOSE_WAIT stage, and timeout is not that serious.

But when i worker_processes=8 in nginx.conf, there are so many timeout, and CLOSE_WAIT stage.

I just **wonder** why lots of timeout exist after setting worker_processes=8, and how to solve it?

**Some relevant code** listed below:

1.**nginx.conf** file as follows(omit some irrelevant lines):

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
include       /data/rd/nginx_spam/conf/mime.types;
sendfile        on; 
keepalive_timeout  65; 
tcp_nodelay        on; 

client_body_in_single_buffer on; 
client_body_buffer_size 16m;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
client_header_buffer_size 256k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 128k;
client_max_body_size 16m;

server {
  listen   9002;

  client_body_in_single_buffer on;
  client_body_buffer_size 16m;
  client_header_buffer_size 256k;
  client_max_body_size 16m;
}
```

2.**deal with redis** as below code, rds_ctx is initialized as a golbal var

```
void process_uid_balcklist_strategy(const text_info &info, redisContext *rds_ctx, rule_result &judge_res_rule) {                                        
  string redis_cmd = "GET " + info.from_source_type + "_Bfuid_" +   info.from_uid;
  redisReply *reply = (redisReply*)redisCommand(rds_ctx, redis_cmd.c_str());
  if (reply && reply->type != REDIS_REPLY_ERROR) {
    int level = 0; 
    if (reply->str) level = string_to_int(reply->str);
    if (level > 0) { 
      judge_res_rule.hit_rule += "fuid_black ";
      judge_res_rule.level = max(judge_res_rule.level, level);
  }    
  }
    if (reply) freeReplyObject(reply);
}
```